# Motorola Xoom PDF/PPT View

Tags: android, pdf, webview, powerpoint, xoom

I need to develop a Sales app specifically targeted for Android on Motorola Xoom. The app needs to display some pdf and ppt files bundled within the apk itself.
The documents should display from within the app itself as the document viewer UI screen should be customisable (client logo etc.) so calling an Intent for some preinstalled document renderer is not an option.
I then tried displaying the pdf in Webview but with no success.
I tried using an opensource pdf renderer but the performance and quality of rendering were very low.
I then converted the pdf as images offline and rendered the images in webview but the quaity is again inferior.

Please guide as I'm at my wit's end. Are there any more approaches left? What can be best way forward?

Comment: Have you come to any conclusion?

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056410/pdf-rendering-on-android/6889135#6889135

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be [ACTION_VIEW intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW), which will let user choose the PDF reader to view the file.